# Prove $\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$

Tags: trigonometry

How do you prove the following trigonometric identity: $$ \sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$$

I'm curious to know of the different ways of proving this depending on different characterizations of sine and cosine.

Comment: By definition? This really depends on how the functions are defined to begin with.

Comment: Look at the unit circle!

Comment: Do you know pythagorean theorem?

Comment: @ncmathsadist: Ok, this isn't homework. I've posted this question for the sake of curiosity of how many different strategies there are to proving this. Also, How do I make this a community wiki?

Comment: What's with the last two sentences? They're phrased like you're giving us homework...

Comment: @anon: oh god, I'm so sorry, I deleted those lines. Again I wanted to see the different way in which mathematicians prove simple stuff like this. Even I've submitted a proof.

Comment: I do not understand why some people have voted down this question while at the same time so many people have rushed to offer their isnight. It might seem a simple question but there are indeed many ways to prove that identity.

Comment: @JohnK: Exactly the reason why I asked this queston. I think the downvotes are because of my careless use of words. All those people must have mistaken me for someone cheating on homework or something like that but if they would have bothered to read the comments here, then most of them wouldn't have done what they did.

Comment: @Dylan: Oh, I'm sorry. I know I know, in order to get the right answer, I must first ask the right question. I have read Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy, I know the significance of that but you can't expect me to word each and every question I ask in the best possible way each and every time. I'm only human. Also, I've added the simplest definition of sin and cos in my question. Please help me to better my question.

Comment: Please don't close this question. Tell me what I should add. Where I can improve my question. Why is there such a big fuss over this?

Comment: Great, I think now JohnK's answer answers your question well!

Comment: @DylanYott: As much I like JohnK's standard answer, I consider all these answers good ways of proving it.

Comment: Close voters: according to the edit "I'm curious to know of the different ways mathematicians approach this kind of question", I highly doubt this is no effort homework.

Comment: I agree with @julien, I think this is a reasonable question and apologize if I initially came off as rude.

Comment: I proposed a cosmetic edit. Some people don't like useless large fonts. Just rollback if you disagree.

Comment: How can this be homework, OP sure knows google has it. Everyone who voted to close needs to re-think their thinking process. This is a SOP.

Comment: The put on hold statement says `This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.` I have no difficulties. This is not homework. I **want** different levels of answering because I want to know how different mathematicians prove this in different ways. This community will always be regarded as a place for little children to cheat on their homework if all of you keep assuming that every question that sort of looks like homework is homework without even enquiring!

Comment: I am *so* surprised that this is not a duplicate.  But, I think it is a canonical question that we need on Math.SE just because it is fundamental to so many other theorems/facts.  (Voting to reopen.  Which, by the way, is something I rarely do.)

Comment: @anorton: You will not believe how many fundamental things are not asked to be proved on M.SE ... But now I'm afraid if I ask those things they will be treated the same way as this question was.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: Yes, I know the pythagorean theorem, I provided an answer using it.

Comment: @Nick There will always be a fight to prove some fundamental stuff (as it could be homework), but I wouldn't let that stop you. :)

Comment: @anorton: How do it, anorty? How do I make them believe?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/572585/fundamental-theorem-of-trigonometry

Comment: Nice question and nice title, you managed to get this question into the Hot Network Questions bar with your snappy title. ;)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Let $(\mathscr C)$ be a unit circle, and $\mathrm M\in(\mathscr C)$. Also, we will denote $\rm \angle{IOM}$ as $\theta$ (see the diagram). From the unit circle definition, the coordinates of the point $\rm M$ are $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$. And so,  $\rm \overline{OC}$ is $\cos \theta$ and $\rm \overline{OS}$ is $\sin \theta$. Therefore, $\rm OM=\sqrt{\overline{OC}^2+\overline{OS}^2}=\sqrt{\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta}$. Since $\rm M$ lies in the unit circle, $\rm OM$ is the radius of that circle, and by *definition*, this radius is equal to $1$. It immediately follows that: $$\color{grey}{\boxed{\,\displaystyle\color{black}{\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1}}}$$

$\phantom{X}$[image: unit circle]

Comment: The unit circle definition is just downright beautiful because just by existing it proves the identity. No tricks, no complication, just simplicity.

Answer (score 104):

Let me contribute by this so let
$$f(\theta)=\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta$$
then it's simple to see that
$$f'(\theta)=0$$
then
$$f(\theta)=f(0)=1$$

Comment: I think it is a wrong solution. To prove the formulas $(\sin(x))'=\cos(x)$ and $(\cos(x))'=\sin(x)$  we have to know  the main trigonometric  identity.

Comment: @Leox [Series definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Series_definitions). There are other alternatives too.

Comment: you don't need to know that identity,one way is by using the Taylor expansion of $\sin(x)$ and you obtain the derivative since it is just a polynomial.

Comment: I known this idea for proving the identity $\arcsin(x)+\arccos(x)=\pi/2$ but I never think to use it for the fundamental trig identity! +1 to you Sami

Comment: @Sami Ben Romdhane How do we get last implication? Where did it come from?

Comment: Since $f'$ is equal to zero then $f$ is a constant on $\Bbb R$ so any value gives this constant@AB_

Comment: How come first derivative of the function equals zero, from which the solution was obtained?

Answer (score 37):

Since all methods are accepted, take the complex exponential defined as its series and consider the complex definitions of the trigonometric functions:

$$\cos (z)=\dfrac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}\, \land \, \sin(z)=\dfrac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}, \text{ for all }z\in \mathbb C.$$

Take $\theta \in\mathbb R$. The following holds:
$$\begin{align} (\cos(\theta))^2+(\sin (\theta))^2&= \dfrac{e^{ 2i\theta}+2+e^{-2i\theta}}{4}-\dfrac{e^{2i\theta}-2+e^{-2i\theta}}{4}\\
&=\dfrac {2-(-2)}4=1.\end{align}$$

Comment: See this is the type of answer I wanted something different and not always thought of (not by highschoolers atleast) Thank you for this.

Comment: Glad to have found this! All the other proofs here are based on the Pythagorean theorem or on other trigonometric identities. This one's truly unique!

Answer (score 24):

Consider a right-angled triangle, $\Delta ABC$, where $\angle BAC = \theta$,

[image: triangle ABC]

By the [Pythagorean theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem),
$$ {AC}^2+{BC}^2 = {AB}^2 $$
Dividing by $AB^2$,
$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
&\Rightarrow \frac{AC^2}{AB^2} + \frac{BC^2}{AB^2} = \frac{AB^2}{AB^2}\\
&\Rightarrow \Big(\frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{hypotenuse}}\Big)^2 + \Big(\frac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{hypotenuse}}\Big)^2 = \frac{\cancel{AB^2}}{\cancel{AB^2}} = 1\\
&\Rightarrow \boxed{\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: This is a nice "first proof" to show someone as it only requires the basics of trigonometry; for pedagogical purposes I'd note the disadvantage of this proof is that it only handles acute angles. The unit circle proof is very similar in spirit - indeed you can apply Pythagoras - but does work for all angles.

Comment: @Silverfish: I agree and it is for that reason, that I had chosen the unit circle answer above all others (even the amazingly good ones). But FYI, the above *first proof* can be extended for all angles since **an obtuse angle can be expressed as the sum of a number of acute angles**. It's conceptually simple but geometrically complicated for $\theta > 2\pi$ (but if you apply certain results, you can reduce it back down to simple) and due to its trivial nature, I leave it an exercise for your imagination.

Comment: I agree. I'm only noting that pedagogically you probably don't want to use the angle sum formula because that's usually taught later, and doing it diagrammatically gets a bit messy compared to how "clean" the unit circle is. But it's possible.

Comment: @Silverfish: Hence, we have reached a consensus. All hail $x^2 + y^2 = 1$

Answer (score 15):

$$\large \sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta
=\sin\theta\sin\theta+\cos\theta\cos\theta
=\cos(\theta-\theta)
=\cos0
=1$$

Comment: You must know $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$ in order to prove the subtraction formula.

Comment: @egreg: I know this is sorta like proving addition using multiplication but this is a proof none the less isn't it?

Comment: No, it proves nothing, unless you provide a definition of sine and cosine and show the subtraction formula without using the Pythagorean identity.

Comment: @egreg: Ah yes, I've been meaning to ask someone that. Can I say in my question that it's ok to assume either definition of sine and cosine in answering?

Comment: There may be a way to characterize sine and cosine in terms of their addition formulae. I recall this being a Putnam problem, can anyone comment?

Comment: @DylanYott Sine and cosine can be characterized as the differentiable functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f'=g$, $g'=-f$, $f(0)=0$ and $g(0)=1$. Then proving $f(x)^2+g(x)^2=1$ is easy (once the existence is proved).

Comment: Actually, this is what I was looking for: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3356/uniqueness-of-sin-x-and-cos-x-putnam-exam-problem?rq=1

Comment: @DylanYott: That question is just Brilliant. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: @egreg Er... are you sure? You can prove the subtraction formula from the fact that rotation is linear.

Comment: @JackM I can't understand your objection. The above “reasoning” shows nothing *unless* we're told what definition of sine and cosine is used.

Comment: @egreg ok then, so give me 1 proof of the formulas in question (that is, the angle sum/difference formulas,) that uses $\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=1$. Don't be so confident. Jack M was basically saying what's in here... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HIYKPTqXnTc . What do you think (video's a bit slow though)?

Comment: "You must know $sin^2(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta)=1$ in order to prove the subtraction formula." is just plain wrong.

Comment: @PineappleFish Really? Definitely with the geometric definition.

Comment: @egreg yeah with the geometric definition of sine and cosine.

Answer (score 15):

If you choose to define sine and cosine by trigonometric rations, then JohnK's answer answers your question. There are other ways of answering your question that go with the different definitions of sine and cosine. Here are a few:

$(1)$, $\sin(x)$ is the solution to the differential equation $y''=-y$, $y(0)=0$, $y'(0)=1$, and $cos(x)$ is its derivative.

Proof of identity using $(1)$: $(\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x))'=(y^2+y'^2)'= 2yy' + 2y'y''= 2yy'-2yy'=0$, now letting $x=0$ gives the identity. This is similar to Isaac's answer.

$(2)$, $\sin(x)= x-\frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \ldots$ and $\cos(x)$ is its derivative.

Proof of identity using $(2)$: Define $e^{x}$ by its power series. Now show $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$, and use Git Gud's answer.

As you can see, these proofs are related, so its all a matter of definitions. I hope that helps :)

Comment: *hugs* At first I thought you weren't very nice because you were shoving me into a corner but now I think you're absolutely splendid for teaching me something I didn't know. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help! Sorry for seeming a bit mean at first, that was completely unintentional. I do like this question and think its important to see that the different proofs of this fact come from the fact that there are different definitions of sine and cosine.

Answer (score 13):

In the spirit of Git Gud's answer, differentiate $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta$ to get

$$ 2 \sin \theta \cos \theta - 2 \cos \theta \sin \theta = 0$$

So $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta$ is constant. Plugging in $\theta = 0$ shows that constant is $1$.

Comment: This is exactly the solution given by Sami Ben Romdhane above!

Answer (score 11):

Well it comes directly from the Pythagorean theorem. We know that in a right triangle, $\cos {\theta}=\frac{h}{r}$ and $\sin{\theta}=\frac{v}{r}$, $h$ is short for horizontal and $v$ for vertical, $r$ is the hypotenuse.

Now, from the Pyth. theorem

$$r^2=v^2+h^2=r^2 \sin^2{\theta}+r^2 \cos^2{\theta} \Leftrightarrow \cos^2{\theta}+\sin^2{\theta}=1$$

By the way, the Pythagorean theorem is one of the oldest theorems of mathematics. Archaelogists have discovered it inscribred in stones in excavations in Babylon!

Comment: This identity is true for values of $\theta$ that are both smaller than zero and larger than 180 degrees which are not usually seen inside a right triangle. I feel there should some extra justification added when appealing to Pythagoras.

Answer (score 11):

We can define(!) the (first only $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$)  functions $\sin$ and $\cos$ via $\exp(it)=\cos t+i\sin t$ and the (complex) exponential as unique(!) solution of the differential equation $f'(z)=f(z)$ with $f(0)=1$. 
We need only a few properties of $\exp$ that quickly follow from uniqueness of the solution:

- Since $z\mapsto\frac1{\exp a}\exp(z+a)$ is also a solution whenever $\exp(a)\ne 0$, we conclude by uniqueness that $\exp(a+b)=\exp(a)\exp(b)$ whenever $\exp(a)\ne0$.
- Specifically, $\exp(a)=0$ implies $\exp(a/2)=0$, hence $\exp(2^{-n}a)=0$. As $\exp(0)\ne0$ and $2^{-n}a\to 0$ and $\exp$ is continous, we conclude $\exp(a)\ne0$ for all $a$. Therefore $\exp(a+b)=\exp(a)\exp(b)$ for all $a,b$.
- Since $z\mapsto\overline{\exp(\overline z)}$ is also a solution, we conclude $\exp\overline z =\overline{\exp z}$ for all $z$.

This makes
$$ \begin{align}\cos^2t+\sin^2t&=(\cos t+i\sin t)(\cos t-i\sin t)\\
&=\exp(it)\cdot\overline{\exp(it)}\\
&=\exp(it)\cdot\exp(\overline{it})\\
&=\exp(it)\cdot\exp(-it)\\&=\exp(it-it)\\&=\exp(0)\\&=1.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 8):

**$\mathbb{}$$\mathbb{}$$\mathbb{}$Hint:**

[image]

Comment: Nice P.S. comment, in the future you can also put \$\mathbb{}$ to fill space when you don't have anything left to say.

Answer (score 7):

Going from the opposite/hypotenuse and adjacent/hypotenuse definitions:

Let $\theta\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ be an angle (in radians, of course) in a right triangle. Let $a$ be the length of the side of a triangle opposite from the angle $\theta$, $b$ the length of the side adjacent to the angle, and $c$ the length of the hypotenuse. Then, $$\sin^{2}\theta+\cos^{2}\theta=\left(\frac{a}{c}\right)^{2} + \left(\frac{b}{c}\right)^{2} = \frac{a^{2}}{c^{2}}+\frac{b^{2}}{c^{2}}=\frac{a^{2}+b^{2}}{c^{2}}=\frac{c^{2}}{c^{2}}=1.$$

To get this result for $0\leq\theta\leq 2\pi$, note that the higher angles only determine the sign of $\sin$ and $\cos$ when a right triangle is formed by going out some length $c$ at angle $\theta$ in the plane and dropping a line perpendicular to the $x$-axis, and since the sign of $\sin$ and $\cos$ don't matter when squaring, the result still holds. To extend the result further to all $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$, note that we just extend the values of $\sin$ and $\cos$ with period $2\pi$ so that we can use any $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$, and it holds trivially.

Answer (score 6):

On one hand,
$$
\int_0^x\sin(x)\cos(x)dx= \int_0^x\sin(x)d(\sin(x))dx=  \frac{1}{2}\sin^2(x),
$$
On the other hand,
$$
\int_0^x\sin(x)\cos(x)dx= -\int_0^x\cos(x)d(\cos(x))dx=- \frac{1}{2}\cos^2(x)+  \frac{1}{2},
$$
Hence, by subtraction, we will have that, 
$$
0= \frac{1}{2}\sin^2(x)+ \frac{1}{2}\cos^2(x)- \frac{1}{2}
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1.
$$
I have not seen this proof elsewhere. It is fun.

Comment: Welcome. Email and signatures are not to be used here; every post is already signed with your usercard. Regarding your proof, it could be also expressed as $(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)'=0$ combined with $\sin(0)=0$ and $\cos(0)=1$.

Answer (score 6):

**Proof by using Euler's theorem: $e^{i\theta}=(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$**

We know that $i^2=-1$, hence $$\color{red}{\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta}$$ $$=\cos^2\theta-i^2\sin^2\theta$$
$$=(\cos\theta)^2-(i\sin\theta)^2$$
$$=(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)(\cos\theta-i\sin\theta)$$
$$=(e^{i\theta})(e^{-i\theta})=e^0=\color{red}{1}$$

Answer (score 4):

Here are two proofs using only the angle sum identities, the fact the trig functions are periodic, and their values at $0$. It is inspired on the connection to rotations and the fact that rotations don't change the sizes of things, but do not actually assume that connection.

Define the matrix

$$ A(\theta) = \left( \begin{matrix} \cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\ -\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \end{matrix} \right) $$

By the angle addition formula, we see that $A(\theta + \varphi) = A(\theta) A(\varphi)$; in particular, $A(n \theta) = A(\theta)^n$.

There are arbitrarily large integer multiples of $\theta$ that are arbitrarily close to integer multiples of $2 \pi$, which gives

$$ A(\theta)^n = A(n \theta) \approx I $$

where $I$ is the identity matrix. By taking determinants, we get

$$ (\cos(\theta)^2 + \sin(\theta)^2)^n \approx 1$$

for arbitrarily large $n$; since the determinant is a real nonnegative number, the only possibility is that

$$ \cos(\theta)^2 + \sin(\theta)^2 = 1$$

---

To get the details right, we select sequences of integers $a_n, b_n$ with

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \theta - 2 \pi b_n = 0 $$
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = +\infty $$

e.g. this can be done by continued fractions. Then,

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} A(a_n \theta) =
\lim_{n \to \infty} A(a_n \theta - 2 \pi b_n)
= A(0) = I$$

and consequently

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}  (\det A(\theta))^{a_n} = 1 $$

---

Another method in the same vein is to also define vectors

$$ v(\theta) = \left( \begin{matrix} \sin(\theta) \\ \cos(\theta) \end{matrix} \right) $$

so that $A(\theta) v(\varphi) = v(\theta + \varphi)$

However, we know that for every angle $\theta$:

$$\frac{1}{2} \leq \max(\sin(\theta)^2, \cos(\theta)^2) \leq 1 $$

In particular, we have

$$ \frac{1}{2} \leq \| v(\theta) \| \leq 2 $$

and furthermore, the $v(\theta)$ span $\mathbb{R}^2$.

By comparing the lengths of $v(\varphi)$ and $A(\theta) v(\varphi)$, we know that  all of the eigenvalues of $A(\theta)$ must have magnitude lying between $1/2$ and $2$.

However, this remains true for $A(\theta)^n$, and consequently, all of the eigenvalues of $A(\theta)$ must be roots of unity, and thus the determinant is either $1$ or $-1$, and it can't be $-1$.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you have a circle with radius r centered at the origin. Using the $ x,y,r$ definitions of $\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta)$, we have that a point on our circle $(x,y)$, has $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$. By Pythagorean Theorem, we have $(r\cos\theta)^2+(r\sin\theta)^2 = r^2$ which implies $\cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta) = 1$

Answer (score 4):

Here is a nice proof by squaring the infinite Taylor series of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$.

The proof:

$$\sin x=\frac{x}{1}-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+...=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\\\\\sin^2x=x^2-x^4\left (\frac{1}{1!3!}+\frac{1}{3!1!}\right )+x^6\left (\frac{1}{1!5!}+\frac{1}{3!3!}+\frac{1}{5!1!}\right )-...\\\\\cos x=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+...=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}\\\\\cos^2x\!=\!1\!-\!x^2\left(\!\frac{1}{0!2!}\!+\!\frac{1}{2!0!}\!\right)\!+\!x^4\left(\!\frac{1}{0!4!}\!+\!\frac{1}{2!2!}\!+\!\frac{1}{4!0!}\!\right)\!-\!x^6\left(\!\frac{1}{0!6!}\!+\!\frac{1}{2!4!}\!+\!\frac{1}{4!2!}\!+\!\frac{1}{6!0!}\!\right)\!+...$$We should have shown that the series for both $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ converge absolutely (since we changed the arrangement), but it's obvious since the absolute value of all terms of $\sin x+\cos x$ add up to $e^x$.$$\sin^2x+\cos^2x=\\=1-x^2\left(\frac{1}{0!2!}-\frac{1}{1!1!}+\frac{1}{2!0!}\right)+x^4\left(\frac{1}{0!4!}-\frac{1}{1!3!}+\frac{1}{2!2!}-\frac{1}{3!1!}+\frac{1}{4!0!}\right)-x^6\left(\frac{1}{0!6!}-\frac{1}{1!5!}+\frac{1}{2!4!}-\frac{1}{3!3!}+\frac{1}{4!2!}-\frac{1}{5!1!}+\frac{1}{6!0!}\right)+...=\\\\=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^{2n}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^k\binom{2n}{k}}{(2n)!}$$
Since we can show easily that $\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}=0$ by expanding $(1-1)^n$ using Binom's formula. So:$$\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1-0+0-0+...=1$$

I think it's beautiful.

Comment: This is super. I have also seen the associated animation. I like it!