# Find $\int{\frac{1}{x^4\arctan(x)+x^3+x^2\arctan(x)+x}}dx$

Tags: integration

I've been struggling with this one for a while, but couldn't do it.
$$\int{\frac{1}{x^4\arctan(x)+x^3+x^2\arctan(x)+x}}dx$$
What I tried was factoring like so:
$$I = \int{\frac{1}{(x^2+1)(x+x^2\arctan(x))}}dx$$then substitute $u=\arctan(x)$, which leads to:
$$I=\int{\frac{1}{\tan(u)+u\cdot\tan^2(u)}}du$$which I've tried to solve using trigonometric identities, or even substituting $t = \ln(\tan(u))$, without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method so far is good, and is what I would have done too. The trick now is to write:
$$\int \frac{1}{\tan(u)+u\cdot \tan^2(u)}~du=\int \frac{\cot^2(u)}{u+\cot(u)}~du=\int \frac{\csc^2(u)-1}{u+\cot(u)}~du$$
Where we have used the well-known identity [$\cot^2 (\theta) \equiv \csc^2 (\theta)-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608828/prove-1-cot2-theta-csc2-theta). Now substitute $s=u+\cot(u)$ and thus $ds=1-\csc^2(u)~du$, and you will obtain:
$$\int \frac{\csc^2(u)-1}{u+\cot(u)}~du=-\int \frac{1}{s}~ds$$
Which is easy to evaluate.

Comment: Your u-sub is not right. It should be $ds=(1-cot^2(u))du$, and that changes everything

Comment: @imranfat Are you sure? $s=u+\cot(u)$ gives $\frac{ds}{du}=1-\csc^2(u)=-\cot^2(u)$ after using the identity $\cot^2(u)\equiv \csc^2(u)-1$.

Comment: Ah, those identities....

Comment: Holy smokes I would have never seen that.