# Prove that $x^{2/3}+ y^{2/3}= a^{2/3}$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

$BE=x, FC=y, BC=a$
Then prove that $x^{2/3}+ y^{2/3}= a^{2/3}$ [image]

Comment: Try to apply your decisions and in the future use LaTeX

Comment: Why down votes???

Comment: Poor design, lack of ideas.

Comment: This is not to mention the $ \frac{x}{3}+\frac{y}{3} = \frac{b}{3} \Leftrightarrow x+y = b$

Comment: I think it is all clear. Design and data are sufficient to understand the problem

Comment: All is clear, but the design is still not very, here it is accepted to respect other members, so that it would be pleasant for them to look at your question

Comment: I can try to fix the design, but you will have to attach the ideas yourself

Comment: x^2/3+y^2/3=a^2/3 is the same as $x^2/3+y^2/3=a^2/3 $, which is the same as $x^2+y^2=a^2$ surely?

Comment: Brother mathematics always made to test imagination and approach.if all things become simple then all level of become equal. It will become simple when one solve it in solution with nice idea ok ??

Comment: There's planty of similar triangles there to start working with. Don't you have _any_ progress to share with us? Or do you simply want someone to do your homework for you?

Comment: I think it need additional construction of circle in which power of point theorem  may  be use

Comment: Basic trigonometry on the many similar right triangles, and some algebra will be enough. Try to express each of $x$ and $y$ in terms of $a$ and the angle at $C$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm  brother then use that and please sove this.

Comment: @user9640947: I'm not your brother. And it's **your** homework. We're not a homework solving service.

Comment: @HenningMakholm ok human being?? If you don't know how solve it.then dont make excuses.its not place for debate.and it my homework or what so

Comment: If Henning says he can solve it, then Henning can solve it. Henning has given you some ideas on how to do it – why not try to follow Henning's hint?

Comment: You all are in team to just downvote nothing else.

Comment: $$x = |BD|\cos B = |AB|\cos^2 B= a \cos^3 B \qquad\qquad y = a \sin^3 B$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By similar triangles $\triangle CDF,\triangle ABC$
$$\dfrac{CF}{BC}=\dfrac{AE}{AB}\implies\dfrac y{a\sin B}=\dfrac{a\cos B-x}{a\cos B} \iff x\sin B+y\cos B=a\cos B\sin B\ \ \  \ (1)$$

Similarly, by similar triangles $\triangle DAF,\triangle ABC$

$$\dfrac{AF}{CA}=\dfrac{DF}{AB}\implies\dfrac{a\cos B-x}{a\sin B}=\dfrac{a\sin B-y}{a\cos B}\iff x\cos B-y\sin B=a\cos2B\ \ \  \ (2)$$

Solve  $(1),(2)$ for $x,y$ to find $x=a\cos^3B,y=a\sin^3B$

Use [Prove $\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607103/prove-sin2-theta-cos2-theta-1)

---

---

Alternatively, let $AB=c,CA=b\implies a^2=b^2+c^2\ \ \ \  (3)$

by similarities of the triangles we have $$\dfrac y{c-x}=\dfrac bc\ \ \ \  (4)$$ and $$\dfrac{c-x}{b-y}=\dfrac bc\ \ \ \  (5)$$

Solve  $(4),(5)$ for $x,y$ and use $(3)$